# Symptoms in men and women

Tags: treatment, symptoms

I was reading something about women’s heart attacks and how they are more likely to die from them as doctors are usually taught male symptoms in unis or something. I tried finding something about it but couldn’t find much aside from an article that talks about sexism or something along the lines of that. Is it true that doctors are usually taught male symptoms and this in turn causes higher death count for women for things like heart attacks?

Edit: this is a link to the article but it’s not the original one I read and seems a bit off and doesn’t really talk about what they are taught and stuff but I hope this somewhat helps https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/how-sexist-stereotypes-mean-doctors-ignore-women-s-pain-a7157931.html

Comment: You are basing your question on a single article. Please do more research. Also, please remove the Google part of your link so it directly goes to the article.

Comment: Don't have enough time to write a proper answer with the relevant papers, but yes, this is the case. Here's a long [Guardian article explaining the history of women* in medicine](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/nov/13/the-female-problem-male-bias-in-medical-trials). Preclinical medical trials are often only done in male animals (rats, apes), because the female menstruational cycle is a cause for statistic interference (at least pharma companies claim this). Females are often left out of phase 3 studies for the same reason.

Comment: [cont'd] Regarding the claim with heart attack: [Heart attack survival rates are much lower in women compared to man](https://www.health.harvard.edu/heart-health/the-heart-attack-gender-gap). It is probably difficult attributing this to a specific cause.

Comment: @Narusan The public awareness campaigns around women's MI symptoms seem to imply that part of the cause is people failing to recognize their own symptoms require medical care, but I don't know what the specific data behind that are.

Comment: @Narusan is there another reason for this aside from statistical interference? Also shouldn’t there be preclinical medical trials for both men and women but the results are categorised instead of mixed together to recognise how the symptoms vary between genders and then they could treat these better. On an unrelated note why has this been tied to sexism?